# Colocar un signo de validación

Tags: php, html5

Tengo este código, y como verán este realiza una validación a color si el Id tiene o no registros de pedidos, es verde cuando tiene pedidos y azul cuando no los tiene, a hora en este mismo código necesito que aparezca un * asterisco cuando el código tenga pedidos y cuando no pues que no aparezca nada y solo aparezca el Id sin que desaparezca la validación por colores.

```
        if(in_array(25,$permisosF)){
        if($item->getDnp()){
        $color = '#22B61D';
        }else{
        $color = 'blue';
        }
        echo "<td><a class='modalPedidoLentes' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.modal- 
        pedido-lentes' data-idOrder='" . $item->getId() . "'data-url='". 
        getUrl("Sales","PurchaseOrder","LensesOrder",FALSE,"ajax") ."'  
        style='cursor:pointer;color: $color;'>" . $item->getId() . "</a></td>";
        }else{
        echo '<td>' . $item->getId() . "</td>";
        }
```

Así debería que quedar mas o menos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igual que usas el condicionante para determinar el color, puedes usarlo para darle valor a una variable que podemos llamar `$signo`, y a la cual le asignaremos "*" o cadena vacía. Luego esa variable la anteponemos a la hora de pintar el id:

```
if (in_array(25, $permisosF)) {
    if ($item->getDnp()) {
        $color = '#22B61D';
        $signo = '*';
    } else {
        $color = 'blue';
        $signo = '';
    }
    echo "<td><a class='modalPedidoLentes' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.modal- 
    pedido-lentes' data-idOrder='" . $item->getId() . "'data-url='". 
    getUrl("Sales","PurchaseOrder","LensesOrder",FALSE,"ajax") ."'  
    style='cursor:pointer;color: $color;'>" . $signo . $item->getId() . "</a></td>";
} else {
    echo '<td>' . $item->getId() . "</td>";
}
```

Si no te gusta cómo queda el asterisco junto al id, puedes añadir una columna a la izquierda de la columna Id para pintar el `$signo`.